# Game crash only on iPhone X and iPhone 8 Plus

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, iphone-x

I'm working on game and the game works perfect on all iPhones and iPad expect iPhone X and iPhone 8 Plus

When I add sprite to the scene the game crash (only on iPhone X and iPhone 8 Plus) because the sprite is already added to scene, On others iPhone the app not crash, I think the bug is in my timer, maybe the bug it's the iPhone simulator? What do you think?

Code:

```
  class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var finger = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Finger") //Finger to swipe the biscuit

var biscuit = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Biscuit")

var glass = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Glass")

var defaultbiscuitpos:CGPoint = CGPoint()

var defaultfingerpos:CGPoint = CGPoint()

/*** Drag Biscuit vars ***/
var touchpoint:CGPoint = CGPoint()
var istouching:Bool = false

var fadeoutfinger = SKAction()
var fadeinfinger = SKAction()
var fingergroup = SKAction()
var burnanimtion = SKAction()
var movefinger = SKAction()

let fingertimer:String = "fingertimer"

var isGameover:Bool = false

//Game mode enum

enum gamemode {
case dip
case ready
case out
case gameover

}

//Game mode (Dip,Ready,Out or game over by enum) **Now is Dip
var mymode = gamemode.dip

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

 //Finger
finger.name = "Finger"
finger.position = CGPoint(x: biscuit.position.x + finger.frame.width, y: biscuit.position.y)
defaultfingerpos = finger.position
finger.alpha = 1.0
finger.zPosition = 5

//Start finger timer to make animation
    createTimer(name: fingeranimation, waitt: 3.0, sprite: finger, actioname: fingertimer)

 }

//Finger timer func
func fingeranimation () {


//Check if timer is over 4 seconds and the title is dip
if mymode == gamemode.dip {

    //Add finger to screen
    addChild(finger)

    //Set fade in animation for finger
    fadeinfinger = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 2.0)

    //Set move animation for finger
    movefinger = SKAction.moveTo(y: glass.frame.midX, duration: 2.0)

    //Set fade out animation for finger
    fadeoutfinger = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 2.0)

    fingergroup = SKAction.group([fadeinfinger,movefinger,fadeoutfinger])

    finger.run(fingergroup, completion: {

        //Remove finger from screen
        self.finger.removeFromParent()

        //Return the finger to apper and return the finger to default position
        self.finger.alpha = 1.0
        self.finger.position = self.defaultfingerpos

      })

   }

  }

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
let location = touch.location(in: self)

//Tap on biscuit
if biscuit.contains(location) && mymode != gamemode.gameover   {
    touchpoint = location
    istouching = true
    biscuit.physicsBody?.pinned = false

    //Stop the finger animation timer
    stopTimer(actioname: fingertimer, sprite: finger)
  }
}

//Make timer function
func createTimer (name:@escaping os_block_t , waitt:TimeInterval, sprite:SKSpriteNode?,actioname: String) {

    let myaction = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: waitt), SKAction.run(name)])

    run(SKAction.repeatForever(myaction), withKey: actioname)
}

//Stop timer function
  func stopTimer(actioname:String, sprite:SKSpriteNode?) {

  removeAction(forKey: actioname)
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

// Called before each frame is rendered
if istouching && isGameover == false {
    let dt:CGFloat = 1.0/15
    let distance = CGVector(dx: touchpoint.x - biscuit.position.x, dy: touchpoint.y - biscuit.position.y * 1.65)
    let velocity = CGVector(dx: distance.dx/dt, dy: distance.dy/dt)
    self.biscuit.physicsBody!.velocity = velocity

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no difference between X and the other simulators.  You need to to clean up your code here so that it is readable. Right now I have no idea what is going on because I can't distinguish when we are in a class or when we are in a function

Comment: I edited my code you are on GameScene class

Comment: this code will still fail, your create timer is floating

Comment: You need to provide all of the code to make this  be able to run,  we have no idea what gamemode is, nor what gamemode.dip is, so we have no idea what can possibly be happening.  For some reason you call your fingeranimation before you remove your finger

Comment: OK, I found the bug when I changed the "wait" in createTimer for fingeranimation from 3.0 to 5.0 the app not crash, but I don't know why

Comment: You are not fixing your problem, you are only delaying it

Comment: It’s fixed the crash, I will edit my code in question tomorrow to make it readable

Comment: You did not fix it, you only delayed it. If your car is leaking gas, you dont fix it buy putting in more gas

Comment: I edited my code

Comment: I want you to run this code as is, guarantee it won't compile.  Please stop being lazy, and provide a working example.  If you cannot do this, then I will not help you anymore and will flag this.

Comment: Now you can run it

Comment: I also have a SpriteKit game that ONLY hangs in the simulators for iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone X.  On all other simulators it works fine.  I've determined that the hang occurs at any point in the program that "run"s some SKAction with a closure to be called upon completion.  The SKAction does not appear to execute on the simulator's screen, and the closure never gets called.  I think this is a simulator bug. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: Yeah, it's a simulator bug

Comment: Apple seems to have fixed it in their latest beta release of Xcode.  The iPhone X simulator no longer hangs when calling SKAction with a closure in Xcode 9.1 beta 2.  However, the most recent stable release of Xcode (9.0.1) still hangs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is now fixed with the release of Xcode 9.1.